# Striping attributes in compound list using python

Tags: python, list, strip

When I execute the following code,

```
department=[]
for dpmt in departments:
    department.append(dpmt)
print department
```

the outcome comes out as follows:

```
[('d009', 'Customer Service'), ('d005', 'Development'), ('d002', 'Finance'), ('d003', 'Human Resources'), ('d001', 'Marketing'), ('d004', 'Production'), ('d006', 'Quality Management'), ('d008', 'Research'), ('d007', 'Sales')]
```

I would like to take out the leading character, 'd', in all attributes. I've tried this but it doens't work

```
department.sort()
for id, dpmt in department:
    id=id.lstrip('d')
```

This prints out the same outcome

```
[('d001', 'Marketing'),
 ('d002', 'Finance'),
 ('d003', 'Human Resources'),
 ('d004', 'Production'),
 ('d005', 'Development'),
 ('d006', 'Quality Management'),
 ('d007', 'Sales'),
 ('d008', 'Research'),
 ('d009', 'Customer Service')]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not e.g. `department.append((dpmt[0][1:], dpmt[1]))`, or `for dept_id, dept_name in departments: department.append((dept_id[1:], dept_name))`? Python strings are *immutable*; creating a new string doesn't affect the object in the list.

Comment: I'm pretty novice in this matter and trying to learn every aspect of it! Thanks for the suggestion, @jonrsharpe :)

Answer (score 1):

You're only assigning `id.lstrip("d")` to the name `id` (by the way, don't use names shared by builtins), so the change is not reflected in the list.

```
department[:] = [(id_.lstrip("d"), dpmt) for (id_, dpmt) in sorted(departments)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation: you are changing copies of "keys".

```
department = map(lambda d: (d[0].lstrip('d'), d[1]), department)
```

Try something like this.